# Can multō modify a verb

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If you wanted to say: 'I don't like brown very much' could you translate that as: "Brunus nōn mihi placet multō".  More generally, can 'multō' be used to modify verbs?  Looking at roughly the first 30 sentences which use 'multō' here

[latin packhum](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23multo)

The only instance I see which might lead one to think that is from Seneca:

[Seneca](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1017/13/4/1031-1036#4)

mali rursus non effugiunt inpietatem, quamvis aras sanguine
multo cruentaverint

Which I think means: They could not escape the wickedness of evil, although the altars were stained with blood.

I couldn't figure out if 'rursus' meant 'backwards' or 'on the contrary' and I can't figure out what 'multō' modifies.  If it modifies 'aras' then why is 'multo' in ablative and 'aras' in accusative plural.  If it modifies 'curentaverint' then maybe it means:

the altars were heavily stained with blood.

######UPDATE

In light of the suggestion of 'multum' rather than 'multo' I found this sentence from De Bello Gallico

quibus ad pugnam non multum Crassus confidebat, Caes. BG. 3, 25

Comment: Are you sure that *sanguine multo* is not just the ablative of *sanguis multus*?

Comment: o yea, I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [the L&S entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmultus) for *multus* you can see that there are two adverbial usages listed, *multum* (section I.A) and *multo* (section I.B). The first is freely used with verbs. The second occasionally occurs with verbs, but apparently only when the verb has some kind of comparative meaning, as in *multo mavolo/malo* "I much prefer" or *multo anteponentes* "greatly preferring". You could even argue that in such cases *multo* is not directly modifying the verb but the prefix: *multo malo* = *multo magis volo* "I want much more", *multo anteponentes* "placing greatly ahead". So in general, and in the specific case you ask about, *multum* seems like the better choice.

In your Seneca quote, as other commenters have pointed out, *multo* is not an adverb but an adjective agreeing with *sanguine*.

Comment: Cool, thanks...